# What is the "block-content" CSS style?

Tags: css

I am working on a web page markup and found strange CSS classes like "**block-content**" or "**pb-10**". Never saw them before and could not find any documentation in google.

CSS styles from Pixelcave are used. Particularly the "Codebase" package. But I have found nothing about the "block-content" in their documentation

Does anybody know where "block-content" is coming from? Is there any documentation?

```
<div class="block pull-r-l">
    <div class="block-content block-content-full block-content-sm bg-body-light">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="font-size-sm font-w600 text-uppercase text-muted">Stat</div>
                <div class="font-size-h4">100</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share some code? Can you ay which frameworks are being loaded in the website? Probably bootstrap or something?

Comment: Just classes, like pb-10 likely stands for `padding-bottom:10px`. Similar to classes being used with [tailwinds](https://nerdcave.com/tailwind-cheat-sheet)

Comment: CSS styles from Pixelcave are used. Particularly the "Codebase" package. But I have found nothing about the "block-content" in their documentation.

Comment: Added some code

Comment: block-content classes look like they are part of Pixelcave's system. They are visual styling classis in a BEM style format. An example here, https://github.com/awsbot-labs/roundcube-skin-marcos/blob/master/oneui/02%20-%20OneUI%20Source%20(HTML)/src/base_comp_images.html, but what are you trying to achieve? Codebase is a mix of Bootstrap and their own custom classes.

Comment: Classes are just an arbitrary string. On their own, they don't mean anything. You can name a string anything you want.

Comment: @BryceHowitson You can't name CSS classes quite *anything* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors but close to it, at least practically

Comment: @TylerH yes agreed. My point is that a class name has no Google-able meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the documentation. It was included into the Pixelcave package.

The package contains following folders structure:

[image]

I was searching in the "Documentation" and "Get Started" folders. But most of the features are described in the "HTML" folder.

Anyway, thanks everyone for advises. That was really helpful to go through the issue.